# Dynamic table view cell height

Tags: swift

I referred to http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift

However, in the example there is only 2 labels, in my cell I need to have 4.

It is shown in the tutorial that I have to change priority for my content hugging, but with 4 labels, can anyone teach me how should I change them?

I've added estimatedheightforrowatindexpath and tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

[image: my cell]

But unfortunately my cell in now empty instead.

Apparently if i perform a segue from a table view and come back to it. The content loads, with dynamic height. P/S: I did add self.tableView.reloadData() in my viewWillAppear

Thanks in advance for all the help

Answer (score 0):

Set below properties to you all label objects, Then try

```
yourLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
yourLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Comment: didn't solve my problem, and actually there is one thing I didn't mention, will edit now.
Apparently if i perform a segue from a table view and come back to it. The content loads, with dynamic height.
P/S: I did add self.tableView.reloadData() in my viewWillAppear